# Keep getting blank page suitecrm - Nginx - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, sugarcrm, suitecrm

this is my site .conf file:

```
server {

listen      [::]:80;

listen      80;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/suitecrm/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

access_log   /var/log/nginx/suitecrmaccess.log;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/suitecrmerror.log error;

# Block access to stuff in the root
location ~* \.(pl|cgi|py|sh|lua|log|md5)$ {
    return 444;
}

# Block access to data folders
location ~ /(soap|cache|upload|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules|diagnostic|blowfish|emailmandelivery)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi|tpl|log|md5)$ {
return 444;
}

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

The paths are correct, I don't get what could be wrong here, any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the suitecrm.log file to see what it says?

Comment: Hi, yes, it says '[27378][-none-][FATAL] Configuration variable date.timezone is not set, guessed timezone America/Caracas. Please set date.timezone="America/Caracas" in php.ini!'

Comment: But weird thing is that I saw and fixed this, but still getting that error, don't know what else to do

Comment: Actually the error disappeared from suitecrm.log, still getting that blank page though

Comment: If I activate the error reporting on index.php says this: Strict Standards: Declaration of SugarEmailAddress::save() should be compatible with SugarBean::save($check_notify = false) in /usr/share/nginx/html/suitecrm/include/SugarEmailAddress/SugarEmailAddress.php on line 0

Comment: Is this a new installation?

Comment: Hi @DigitalMcGrath I solved it by reinstalling suitecrm :/ Thank You very much, no it wasn't a new install